# how to show the result of a router from the sideBar to the content component using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, windows

I'm new to react and I have been trying to find an example of how to use a router inside my SideBar component so the issue is that the result displays on the sidebar, not on the content of the page. any help, please!

I'm using react js with node.js

```
// App.js


import 'babel-polyfill';
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Header from './Header';
import Content from './Content';
import SideBar from './SideBar'


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <SideBar />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


//sideBar

<li className="treeview">
  <a href="#">
    <i className="fa fa-cogs"></i>
    <span>Configuratin</span>
    <span className="pull-right-container">
      <i className="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
    </span>
  </a>
  <ul className="treeview-menu">
    <Router>
      <li>
        <Link to="/pages/charts/chartjs">Projects Setings</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/conf">ReqTool Configuration</Link>
      </li>
      <Route path="/conf" component={conf} />
    </Router>
  </ul>
</li>
```

[this is the result of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvQ8V.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the result will display where ever you render the route so if its in the side bar this is where it will render

if you wish to render this outside of the side bar you should wrap more of your app in router (moving it higher in the tree). then you can place the routes inside of it where you wish the to render.